# Proving that if the odd and even sequences converge, where one is decreasing and the other is increasing, then they converge to the same limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, recursion

I'm trying to prove this statement for this sequence as a part of a larger proof. 
The specific sequence I'm looking at is : $b_{n+1} = 1+\dfrac{1}{b_n}$, where $b_1 = 2$. I'm attempting to show that ($b_{2n}) \rightarrow A \land (b_{2n-1}) \rightarrow B \implies A=B$.
I know that this statement is not true in all cases, e.g. if $b_n = (-1)^n$. For this reason, I think I might have to use the fact that for this specific sequenence, $(b_{2n})$ is monotonic increasing and $(b_{2n-1})$ is monotonic decreasing. 
Note that I am not assuming that $(b_n)$ converges from the start, and I am not trying to show that it converges to the same value as the subsequences.
Is the statement: "if the odd and even sequences converge, where one is decreasing and the other is increasing, then they converge to the same limit" even true in general? If so, how do I go about proving it? I'm completely stuck on how to proceed with the information that I seem to have.

Comment: $b_n = (-1)^{n+1}(1+\frac 1n)$ is a counter-example.

Comment: I see. Is there something else unique to this sequence that makes this statement true?

Comment: As pointed out in the duplicate Q&A, you need that the difference converges to zero. In your case $b_{2n-1} - b_{2n} \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks. I asked another question to do with that since I have no idea on how to prove the difference converges to 0.